# regex match square brackets once

Tags: regex, awk

There is a text file with the following info:

```
[[parent]]

[son]

[daughter]
```

How to get only [son] and [daughter]?

```
$0 ~ /\[([a-z])*\]/        ???
```

Comment: Be aware that `[a-z]` does NOT necessarily only match lower case letters, assuming that's what you want. Depending on your locale setting `[a-z]` could match `aAbBcC...yYz` or something else. To always only match lower case letters use the POSIX character class `[[:lower:]]` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your regex is almost right. Just put the `*` inside the round brackets (in order to have the whole text inside the only group) and remember to use the `^` and `$` delimiters (to avoid matching `[[parent]]`):

```
^\[([a-z]*)\]$
```

Answer (score 3):

Match any square bracket at beginning of line where the next character is an alphabetic.

```
awk '/^\[[a-z]/' file
```

You might want to add uppercase and/or numbers to the character class, depending on what your real requiements are. (Your examples show only lowercase, so I have assumed that's a  valid generalization.)

Comment: Yes, I needed only lowercase. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use this awk command:

```
awk -F '[][]+' 'NF && !/\[\[/{print $2}' file
son
daughter
```

**awk command breakup:**

```
-F '[][]+'     # set input field separator as 1 or more of [ or ]
NF             # only if at least one field is found
!/\[\[/        # when input doesn't start with [[
```